# Self signed certificate converted to CA verified

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority

I'm using a self signed certificate for a number of SSL connections. However I have one connection that needs the cert to be CA authenticated.

Now if I use the same self signed certificate and create a certificate authority request 
and import what I receive, will anything have to change on my existing direct trust SSL connections ?

what exactly will having the cert CA verified change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same question. The answer is that the certificate signing request is used by the CA to generate a public key. This can then be used on the server as a CA verified cert.

Typically your application / server should have a location / import operation for this.